# jQuery get selected object upon definition

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

I am using a code like this to animate my slide elements. Note, this is more of a jquery question rather than a flexlider question.

Now, in flexslider I can define a jQuery object to pass as an argument, like this to specify the container of the controls for the slider:

```
$('.header-slider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    directionNav: false,
    slideshowSpeed: 5000,
    controlsContainer: $('.header-slider .controls-container')
});
```

All good, but later on when I will define a second slider, let's take it step by step, I copy-paste for my second slider the above code like this

```
$('.quote-slider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    directionNav: false,
    slideshowSpeed: 5000,
    controlsContainer: $('.quote-slider .controls-container')
});
```

Works like a charm, as expected. However, now we have ugly code, so let's clean it up, since the options are the same for both sliders, I want to make this more general into one class and here's the next step:

```
$('.slider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    directionNav: false,
    slideshowSpeed: 5000,
    controlsContainer: $(this).find('.controls-container')
});
```

Nope, here's where the problem comes in. Naturally, `$(this)` is referring to the document ! So, what can I do in the above code (last block) to tell jQuery that I want to refer to the currently selected `'.slider'` and not the document ? Obviously, if I only pass $('.controls-container') as an argument I will get double options in both sliders, so I don't want that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, `$(this)` will not be pointing to the element you're calling `flexslider()` on. To fix this you need to place the `flexslider()` call within scope of the element by placing it in an `each()` call, like this:

```
$('.slider').each(function() {
    $(this).flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        directionNav: false,
        slideshowSpeed: 5000,
        controlsContainer: $(this).find('.controls-container')
    });
});
```

Comment: Ah right, interesting solution, thank you ! But, is this the only solution ? Does jQuery not have a way to refer to the current element inside stacked rules ?

Comment: It's not a jQuery issue, but a JS one as it's scoped at function level.

Comment: Hmmm, I see. Alright, thanks for your fast and clear help !